# How to hide the BarButtonItem on the ToolBar?

Tags: iphone

I have a UIView tha contain a ToolBar,and I add some BarButtonItem on the ToolBar.
Now I want to hide the BarButtonItem in some time ,and display them in some time ,how can  i accomplish it ??

Answer (score 6):

Change your `toolbar.items` accordingly.

For example if you had `toolbar.items` set to `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: button1, button2, nil]` and you need to hide button1, do `toolbar = [NSArray arrayWithObject: button2]`

Comment: i think you meant `toolbar.item = [NSArray arrayWithObject:button2]`. Nota : the `toolbar` object is available in `self.navigationController.toolbar` where `self` is a `UIViewController` embedded in a Navigation Controller